# mysql-connector-pythonで同じレコードがあるかどうかを判定するプログラムを書きたい

Tags: python, mysql

mysql-connector-pythonで、同じレコードがあるかどうかを判定したいです。

環境
・mysql（最新版）
・python(3.9.1)
・mysql-connector-python(最新版）

sql文には以下のような設定がされています。

```
CREATE TABLE likes (
tweet_number int NOT NULL,
user_number int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
like_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
primary key (tweet_number, user_number));
```

python側では以下のようなコードにしています

```
def like(interger, username):
    try:
        cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO likes (tweetnumber,username,liketime) values("{}","{}","{}")'.format(interger,
                                                                                          username,
                                                                                          datetime.datetime.today()))
        except mysql.connector.errors:
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM likes where num = {}'.format(interger))
```

エラー文です。

```
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

どのようにすれば、mysql-connector-pythonで同じレコードがあるかどうかを判定できますか？
また、mysql-connector-pythonのdocumentはどこにありますか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ドキュメントは恐らくこちらかと思います。 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityErrorをtryに設定すれば良いので、

```
def like(interger, username):
    try:
        cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO likes (tweetnumber,username,liketime) values("{}","{}","{}")'.format(interger,
                                                                                              username,
                                                                                              datetime.datetime.today()))
    except mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError:
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM likes where num = {}'.format(interger))
```

のようにすればいよかったです。
ありがとうございます。